# css component animation is moving the parent component

Tags: css, animation

I have a component in my dashboard with a button, when I click the button, a sidebar modal opens on the side, sliding in from the right. However, when I open it, instead of having the sidebar modal floating in from the right, I have the sidebar just appear without animation, and the parent component is sliding instead of it, from the left.

When I close the modal, the sidebar is sliding as planned outside of the parent modal and disappear. How can I make the modal opening animation in in the correct order?

parent component:

```
.parent-widget {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: hidden;
```

sidebar modal:

```
@keyframes sidebar-open-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes sidebar-close-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }
}

.inline-sidebar-modal-container {
    .sidebar {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        right: 0;
        width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        animation: sidebar-open-animation 0.3s linear;

        &.closing {
            animation: sidebar-close-animation 0.3s linear;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to add to your `&.closing` section the `transform: translateX(100%);` value.
Your code seem to work (that part of code, you've shared here).

Check this fiddle (i used a jsfiddle, because of the scss styling)
https://jsfiddle.net/v8ck3pjg/41/

If you add `closing` to the sidebar and press "run" on the top left, it moves correctly to the right.
That's the effect you wanted, or not?

Comment: thank you but no, if I look at your results, what is happening to me, is that the red sidebar will just pop open, and the green background will slide to the right untill it meets the red. adding the transform to the closing did not end, the problem is with the opening.

Comment: the green background is moving in your code?

Comment: exactly, if I do an analogy from my front end to your jsfiddle, instead of having the green background static and the red sliding left and right, the red will slide right on closing just fine, but opening to to left will work as i described.